# Database often becomes unavailable and Mysql has error log

Tags: mysql, error-log

The service is a droplet in DO with Ubuntu 16.04 and apache2
MySql database often becomes unavailable in this server.
here is the log from /etc/log/mysql/error.log

```
2018-08-19T18:39:41.534354Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2018-08-19T18:39:41.534424Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2018-08-19T18:39:41.711277Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-08-19T18:39:41.713157Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 22330 ...
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718519Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718551Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718556Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718560Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718566Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718581Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-08-19T18:39:41.718907Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-08-19T18:39:41.719038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721028Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721078Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721087Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721092Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721098Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721102Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721107Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721110Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-08-19T18:39:41.721120Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721170Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721193Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721567Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Need a fix, tried with lots of solutions on several forums but couldn't get a proper shot.

```
root@np:/# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            992         353         260          74         378         394
Swap:             0           0           0


root@np:/# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf

#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M
```

---

```
root@np:~# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
[mysql]
```

---

```
root@np:~# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
```

---

```
root@np:~# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3895
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3895
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

---

```
root@np:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            487M     0  487M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/vda1        25G  4.6G   20G  19% /
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

---

```
root@np:~#htop
```

[image: htop]

---

mysql>SHOW GLOBAL STATUS

https://pastebin.com/q6s3bfq1

---

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
```

https://pastebin.com/1ifB9x24

---

```
root@np:~# iostat -x
Linux 4.4.0-133-generic (npk)   08/21/2018      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.19    0.00    0.88    0.12    0.00   96.81

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
loop0             0.00     0.00    0.01    0.00     0.01     0.00     3.20     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
vda               0.00     3.06   17.73    2.73   305.75    62.00    35.95     0.01    0.27    0.10    1.35   0.10   0.21
```

---

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop or top or mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Your ulimit -a report will indicate open files of 1024, use of ulimit -n 16384 will increase the capacity and the first two lines in the error log will no longer be reported.  You will need to make the ulimit -n change persistent across OS restart by reviewing the content of this url and taking similar action
  https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is pure admin issue, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Dba or serverfault sister sites can offer you better assistance in such questions.

Comment: Thanks to the moderator for moving this from SO Questions 51920801 to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AnupRaj Please post informantion requested a few hours ago.  Someone will offer suggestions with additional details available from you.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck the question is edited and updated :)

Comment: @AnupRaj  The top display indicates 30 copies of mysqld are in memory at 168M each of RAM.  So, with your ~1G RAM you are trying to support 5G and you have NO swap space.  Review your doc on how to kill a process in your OS and kill 29 of the PID's listed on top report.  The my.cnf posted has 2 include lines requesting files to be used at startup.  Please post the named files so we can see your 'configuration' details.  Not sure that multiple apache2 PID's listed in top are reasonable.   Probably also need to be killed by you, especially if they are more than a minute old according to time.

Comment: @AnupRaj  If you could post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; that would be enlightening for how mysqld is using RAM.  You may be on a system that does not allow SWAP space to be available.  If so, you are just limited to live with available RAM, no matter what is needed to survive.  More diligent management is required when you are in a NO SWAP environment.

Comment: @WilsonHauck you are right about a restricted system to configure SWAP space .. the system has SSD and the doc says SWAP is advantage only for spinning disks

Comment: @AnupRaj Do you use EXIT or QUIT when you are done with a Command Line session with your OS?  Or do you just minimize the Command LIne box?  TOP indicates it is just left idling along.

Comment: @AnupRaj  Do you have Skype available?  With microphone and speakers?  Do you speak English?  If so we will be able to cover much more detail in a few minutes than with this form of chat.  I am on Skype at  wlhauck atsign aol.com

Comment: @WilsonHauck I'm using Bitvise on Win10 after working with terminal I just quit Bitvise. I'm not sure if EXIT or QUIT is required. Is it responsible for the issue?

Comment: @AnupRaj Have you received the Suggestions emailed to anupofuniverse@gmail.com about 4:30 PM yesterday my time?

Comment: @AnupRaj Please Screen Share so I can observe your use of Bitvise with Skype, please.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ran out of memory:

```
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721028Z 0
  [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-08-19T18:39:41.721078Z 0
  [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
```

Since you have only 1GB of memory, there is an issue.  (Side note:  Long ago, I installed mysql on 256MB of RAM, no problem.  But times have changed.)

You could *try* changing this in an attempt to get things stated:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 32M
query_cache_size = 0
```

but the better bet is to get more RAM.

Comment: Tip: see errno 12 in the output, you can translate this using the mysql/mariadb perror command:  `perror 12`  ->  `OS error code  12:  Cannot allocate memory`